# Enforce Spring Boot Application to Fail When Cannot Connect to Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I want to make my spring boot application fail on start if it cannot connect to the kafka broker. My application is only publishing messages to topics. I added this line to my properties file but no luck so far `spring.kafka.admin.fail-fast=true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fail-fast` will only work if there is at least one `NewTopic` bean in the context (so the admin will try to check if the topic exists and create it if not).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So55177700Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So55177700Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so55177700", 1, (short) 1);
    }

}

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-15 09:42:49.555 ERROR 41793 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not configure topics
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So this will create the topic from the running application. What I need is the similar behavior if I consume a topic. In that case application will fail because the method annotated with `KafkaListener` will try to connect the kafka broker and consume message.

Comment: Consumers run on a different thread to the one that starts the application. Adding the topic bean is the only out-of-the box mechanism to do what you want. You can write your own `Lifecycle` bean that connects to the broker in `start()`. But I'm not sure why you would want to since your consumer needs the topic anyway. And, if the topic already exists, nothing will be done, the admin just checks for its presence.

Comment: Is it possible to make it `fail-faster`? In my case, it took the app ~40secs before failing(Forcing a hard I/O thread shutdown), although it's much better than the ~2min40secs, without the `fail-fast` feature.

Comment: It's better to ask a new question rather than commenting on an old answer. It's easier for people to find answers. By all means reference an answer in a new question. You can try reducing the kafka admin client property `request.timeout.ms` from its default (30 seconds). Using Boot, it's `spring.kafka.admin.properties.request.timeout.ms=5000`

Answer (score 2):

Addition on how to speed up fail-fast

**TL;DR** Spring Boot 2.4.5 auto configuration does not let you speed up fail-fast using env parameters. Add this to your @Configuration to get 10 seconds timeout:

```
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin(@Autowired KafkaProperties properties) {
    KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin = new KafkaAdmin(properties.buildAdminProperties());
    kafkaAdmin.setFatalIfBrokerNotAvailable(properties.getAdmin().isFailFast());

    /* speed up fail fast */
    kafkaAdmin.setOperationTimeout(5);
    kafkaAdmin.setCloseTimeout(5);

    return kafkaAdmin;
}
```

**More detailed answer**

Fail-fast occurs when `initialize()` method of class `org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin` is executed. This method may block:

1. If new topics are found, it blocks on topic creation for up to `operationTimeout`

   1. If topic creation failed, it blocks on releasing resources for up to `closeTimeout`

By default those values are 30 and 10 seconds accordingly (hardcoded in the class mentioned above). You can redefine them using set methods: `setOperationTimeout(int sec)`, `setCloseTimeout(int sec)`.

What about Spring Boot? `KafkaAdmin` bean is created in class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration`. As you can guess, Spring Boot simply does not set timeouts:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin = new KafkaAdmin(this.properties.buildAdminProperties());
    kafkaAdmin.setFatalIfBrokerNotAvailable(this.properties.getAdmin().isFailFast());
    return kafkaAdmin;
}
```